# Simplifying factorials

Tags: factorial

I apologise for a repost, but my rep is not high enough to ask in a comment. But, in this question [Simplify sum of factorials with mathematical induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089542/simplify-sum-of-factorials-with-mathematical-induction) I am confused how:

$$(n+1)!-1+(n+1)(n+1)! = -1+(n+1)!(1+(n+1))$$

I expect it's quite simple, but I couldn't for the life of me see the solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $(n+1)!-1+(n+1)(n+1)! = -1+(n+1)!(1+(n+1)) = (n+2)(n+1)!-1$

Comment: Haven't you just rewritten the question?

Comment: When I wrote my answer the question had $n$s and $k$s.  But you are correct: the middle and right hand sides are essentially the left hand side rewritten and tidied up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the actual wording has only one free variable:
$$(n+1)! -1+(n+1)\cdot(n+1)! = -1 + (n+1)!\cdot(1+n+1) = (n+2)! - 1$$
All that is used are the usual distributive law, note that $(n+1)!$ is an integer just like any other and the $!$ just binds the immediately preceeding integer, and the equation
$$n! = n \cdot (n-1)!$$
Here is the same with some highlighting:
$$\begin{align*}
\color{red}{(n+1)!} \color{blue}{- 1} + (n+1) \cdot \color{red}{(n+1)!} & \stackrel{y = (n+1)!}= \color{red}y \color{blue}{-1}+(n+1)\cdot \color{red}y\\
& = \color{blue}{-1} + \color{red}y\cdot(1+(n+1))\\
& = \color{blue}{-1} + \color{red}{(n+1)!} \cdot (1 + (n+1)) \\
& = -1 +(n+1)! \cdot (n+2) \\
& = -1 + (n+2)!
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I see, thank you! I was over complicating it... again.

Comment: I did like one of the answers which got deleted, it said let $y=(n+1)!$, then, $-1+(y+y(n+1))=-1+y(1+(n+1))$

Comment: @ElisJones Do you want me to incorporate this into my answer to make it more elaborate or is the coloring sufficient?

Comment: I found that to be more a little more intuitive. But you're answer is nice as it is.

Comment: @ElisJones I've added it to make it even nicer ;)

Answer (score 0):

$n \cdot n! = (n+1-1)n!=(n+1)n!-n!=(n+1)!-n!$
Now, sum of all this taking $n=1,2,3,...$
$1 \cdot 1!+2 \cdot 2! + 3 \cdot 3! + ... + n \cdot n!$$=(2!-1!)+(3!-2!)+(4!-3!)+...+((n+1)!-n!)=(n+1)!-1!$

Comment: Your post is overlapping to the right and I don't see how it answers the question at hand.

Comment: Sorry, I've just  provided a new method to you.
I didn't read whole the question, I understood you need a general method.

Comment: That should actually be an answer to [the linked question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089542/simplify-sum-of-factorials-with-mathematical-induction), not this one.

Answer (score 0):

For example, to simplify $6!$, substitute $6$ for $n$ in the following equation:$$n!=n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot(n-3)\cdot...$$$$6!=6\cdot(6-1)\cdot(6-2)\cdot(6-3)\cdot(6-4)\cdot(6-5)$$and now simplify:$$6!=6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1$$but you don't have to including the $1$ because it's the same thing as not using it:$$6!=6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2$$Now evaluate it:$$30\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2$$$$120\cdot3\cdot2$$$$360\cdot2$$$$720$$Use the regular equation to help you with not just this, but any whole-number factorial.